# What will happen to the current txs in the mempool post EIP-1559?

Tags: txpool, eip-1559, london

The London hardfork is estimated to go live in ~3 hours at the time of posting this question, which introduces a major change in the transaction pricing mechanism of Ethereum, [EIP-1559](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md).

What will happen to the existing txs in the mempool?

Comment: i think backward compatibility will kick in or those : https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md#backwards-compatibility